# Html radio buttons positioning

Tags: html

How can I create same buttons positioning as on picture with html?

This is how I tried to do it, looks similar, but I'm searching for another way to do it

```html
<center>
  <input type="radio" checked>
</center>
<center>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
</center>
<center>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
</center>
<br>
<center>
  <input type="radio" checked> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;
  <input type="radio" checked>
</center>
<center>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked> &ensp; &ensp; &ensp;
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
</center>
<center>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked> &ensp;
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
  <input type="radio" checked>
</center>
```

[Top right cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw9uq.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried some &nbsp spaces and it looks close enough, but maybe there's another solution

Comment: can you please update the post with your code?

Comment: You haven't tagged with css. Is it an option?

Comment: No, I can use only html

Comment: It seems that your solution looks like the image you are trying to replicate. Please can you explain why you don't think you have achieved that.